# handler this not working - jquery at WP backend

Tags: wordpress

I would like that when Update/Publish button is pressed at Wordpress backend to update/publish a wordpress post:

a) Wordpress still updates/publishes the rest of the contensts of that post

b) jQuery gives a warning message if a URL entered is invalid in a form field at Wordpress backend

c) then clear off or remove that invalid URL above

Here are my codes:

```
    HTML:
    <input type="text" id="url" name="url">

    jQuery:
    var myurl = document.getElementById('url').value;
    var urlRegex = /(^$)|^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|ftp:\/\/www.|www.){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)/;
    if (!urlRegex.test(myurl)) {
      alert('Its invalid URL or website. Make sure to include www');
      $this.val(null);
    //  $(this).val(null);    // not working either
    }
```

I have tried to use $this.val(null); or $(this).val(null); to remove that invalid URL after the post was updated/published, but URL is updated/published by Wordpress too.

Please advise how to achieve the above.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: use jQuery('#url').val(''); instead of $this.val(null); which works only inside a jQuery function. In my case that $this.val(null); does not work. This may be helpful to anyone who need similar solutions.

```
    HTML:
    <input type="text" id="url" name="url">

    jQuery:
    var myurl = document.getElementById('url').value;
    var urlRegex = /(^$)|^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|ftp:\/\/www.|www.){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)/;
    if (!urlRegex.test(myurl)) {
      alert('Its invalid URL or website. Make sure to include www');
      jQuery('#url').val('');
    }
```

Many thanks